# Reactjs=> React App rendering blank page error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<div><App/><h1> Hello </h1></div>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <div className="container">
       <Navbar />
       <br/>
       <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList} />
       <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise} />
       <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise} />
       <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
       </div>
     </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It renders a blank white page but shows no error! App js contains a Nav Bar and other links
I also use react router dom could something be wrong with that??

Comment: Do you see the `<h1> Hello </h1>` rendered? What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router-dom` from your project's directory. What is the error you are seeing? Please include all relevant details in your question. What debugging have you done? Does the `Navbar` render alone? The routes, alone? etc...

Comment: @DrewReese No i can't see the Hello too! this is the react router dom version `react-router-dom@6.2.2` It shows no error on the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component APIs changed significantly from `react-router-dom@5` to `react-router-dom@6`. The `Route` components ***must*** be rendered within a `Routes` component, and the `component` prop was replaced by a single `element` prop that takes a `ReactNode` i.e. JSX.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercise.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<ExercisesList />} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditExercise />} />
          <Route path="/create" element={<CreateExercise />} />
          <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

For more detail regarding all the changes between versions see the [v5-v6 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5).